# How to name a class which only shows a part of a database entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm struggling with a college about a name for a class.
It's basically just a part of a entity stored in the database. On a database you would call it a view but in java it's not that easy, because view is a known term from the mvc pattern.
So has anyone a idea how to call the class, to make clear it's just a part of an entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it a DTO, which stands for Data Transfert Object, as a DTO can be used to partially represent an entity, and name it `*PartialDTO`

Comment: I think you are partially right. For me it also is unfamilar to call something that represents something form a database DTO. Besides from that unlikely we call everything which transfer data (controller responsens and so on) DTO.

Comment: I see what you mean. So what use would these partials have? Because you could name them after their usage

Answer (score 0):

Seems that "ValueObject" might be what you're looking for... at least if the Object you're having in mind is part of the entity and not only a different view on some of the attributes of the Entity.

Like something along those lines

```
@Entity
public class Person

   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @Embeddable
   private Adress adress;
...
```

where Adress would be the ValueObject as Part of the Entity Person.

If it's just a different view on the entity, maybe something containing "Projection"?